# Typescript Conditional Types combined with mapped types documentation example clarification

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand the conditional types introduced in TypeScript 2.8 and reading the documentation for the same.

The below example can be seen in the below link
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

There is an example in the section:

- Distributive Conditional Types

  - Conditional types are particularly useful when combined with mapped types:

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

I understood the part
`{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }`
where it is picking all keys of type Function. But i didn't understand why there is a an array type of syntax at the end
`[keyof T]`
What is it doing there? Why is it required?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)

Using the array access syntax we can get a union of all property types that we pass in.

```js
({ a: string, b: number, c: object })['a' | 'b'] // -> string | number
```

---

Let's look an example where T is:

```js
{
  a: () => void,
  b: () => void,
  c: string
}
```

The expected result of `FunctionPropertyNames<T>` would be `'a' | 'b'`.

The mapped type produces an object type like this:

```js
{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: never
}
```

But that's not what we wanted, we need the property names as union type. This is where the lookup type comes in.

In the example we're using all keys of `T` so basically:

```js
({ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: never })['a' | 'b' | 'c'] // -> 'a' | 'b' | never
```

This returns `'a' | 'b' | never` and `never` doesn't matter so TypeScript removes it and we get `'a' | 'b'`

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation along with the type of the operator( in this case lookup ) which gave me much deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the beginning that the snippet is only the following

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never };
```

without the array accessor. So basically non-functions are mapped to `never` while function are mapped to the key of the respective type, i.e. their function name.

This means that

```
type Foo = FunctionPropertyNames<{
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
    boo(): void;
    ping(a: number): string;
}>;
```

and

```
type Foo = {
    bar: never;
    baz: never;
    boo: "boo";
    ping: "ping";
};
```

are the same. When we finally use the array accessor and access all types of the properties with keys in `T` using the `[keyof T]` (so virtually all at this point) we get a union of all their types without `never` since `never` is always discarded.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.